# google.script.run is broken when used in a shared library

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following code.gs

```
function test() {
  Logger.log("Whoo hoo! test() called");
}

function showPopup() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate().setWidth(400).setHeight(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Click the button');  
}
```

along with this index.html

```
<div>
  <input type='button' onclick='google.script.run.test()' value='Test'>
</div>
```

These work fine: after running showPopup() I click on the button and the message appears in the logs [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lF2BXC1GujEHDRYEjmepQPT1D0jnLf5JgtrZbMLg028/edit?usp=sharing).

The problem comes when I add this project as a library to another spreadsheet, using the "Resources->Libraries..." menu item. Let's say I give the library the name "Test", then on the new spreadsheet I run `Test.showPopup()`, it puts up the popup. But then when I click on the button it does not call the test() function.

Instead, the console on the spreadsheet complains that "undefined is not a function". The problem appears to be that google.script.run.test() does not work when code is shared using the Libraries manager. It wants something like google.script.run.Test.test(), but I tried that and it didn't work either: "Cannot read property 'test' of undefined".

Is there some way I can use google.script.run in a shared (library) script?

or some other way I can re-use my code on other spreadsheets without having to cut-n-paste all the files to each one?

Ah, it looks like someone else [reported this as a bug](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3778). Shucks. Any workarounds?

Comment: Hello, Jose! I have exactly the same situation. If you found a solution, prompt what to do to make it work? Answers from google-apps-script-issues didn't help me

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering the same thing. So far haven't seen an real answer on this. 
My answer is not the best, but I managed a workaround doing this on the script:

```
function test() {
  Test.test();
}
```

I'd love to know the real solution for this.